# Laravel 4 Generating Migration Class Generated, Where?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

What happens when i type php artisan migrate:make create_hi_Table

It says it is generating optimized class loader , compiling common classes.

When i try to create the migration file manually, it says class not found.

what exactly happened and what was created from the artisan migrate:make command.

Just trying to understand how this works :X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are making migration file manually, you have to run `php artisan dump-autoload` to add the class to autoloading list.

This process will add your file entry in an array with `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`

Just look this file.This file will contain namespace reference for all classes.